# Passing data to textView from another class

Tags: objective-c, macos

I know this is just a fundamental question but still somewhere I am missing something, I am playing with passing data to a textView from another class. For this I have created two classes one with xib file (ViewController) and another without(secondVC).

What I am trying to do is that I have a textview in ViewController class and wanted to pass the data to this textView from secondVC. This is how I am doing.

```
//ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "secondVC.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender;

@end


//ViewController.m

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender{

    secondVC *sec = [[secondVC alloc] init];

    [sec print];

}


//secondVC.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface secondVC : UIViewController

- (void)print;

@end


//secondVC.m

- (void)print{

    NSString *printThis = @"This works";

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    [vc.textView setText:printThis];

    //vc.textView.text = printThis  //Tried both
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this :

//ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "secondVC.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender;

@end


//ViewController.m

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender{

    secondVC *sec = [[secondVC alloc] init];
    sec.viewController = self;
    [sec print];

}


//secondVC.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface secondVC : UIViewController {
ViewController *viewController;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain)ViewController *viewController;

- (void)print;

@end


//secondVC.m

@synthesize viewController;

- (void)print{

    NSString *printThis = @"This works";
    self.viewController.textView.text = printThis ; 
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your code, but Im getting an error "Unknown type name viewController" in secondVC.h at ViewController *viewController;
Any idea?

Comment: thanks dude, your code works I solved the Unknown type name viewController problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with protocol... if you want to send string from textView(child) to other ViewController(parent)

Answer (score 0):

You need a delegate method that is fired from the SecondVC and handled in the first one (ViewController).

Answer (score 0):

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol StringDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)getArrayOfStrings:(NSMutableArray*)strArray;


@end



@interface WWSettings : UIViewController{


}

@property(nonatomic,assign)id<StringDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "WWSettings.h"

@implementation WWSettings
@synthesize delegate;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)blablablaFunction{
    [delegate getArrayOfStrings:yourArray];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
@end
```

if you dont understand how it works .. ask ! i'll make my best to help you )

your secondVC

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WWSettings.h"
@interface secondVC : UIViewController<StringDelegate>{


    WWSettings      *obj;



}

@end
```

and .m file :

```
#import "secondVC.h"


@implementation secondVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}




-(void)getArrayOfStrings:(NSMutableArray *)strArray{



    // here you get your array !!! it's a delegate function made by you in child viewController;



}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    obj = [[WWSettings alloc]init];
    [obj setDelegate:self];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your example code, but still seems somewhat unclear to me. Is it possible to give an example to what I was looking for, then it would be more clear, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. You've got a `ViewController` creating a new `secondVC` and sending it a `print` message. That's okay, but the implementation of `-print` creates a *different* instance of `ViewController` and tries to set the text of it's `textView` property. That's clearly not what you want -- you should instead be sending the text back to the original instance of `ViewController`.
2. That second instance of `ViewController` very likely has its `textView` property set to nil since `textView` is an outlet, but you haven't loaded its view from the .xib.
3. It's *really* not nice for one view controller to mess with the views of another view controller. The `secondVC` should be giving the text to the original `ViewController` object, not trying to set the text of one of its views.
4. To facilitate communication from `secondVC` to `ViewController`, give `secondVC` a property to keep track of the original `ViewController`. The usual thing to do here is to define a delegate protocol for `secondVC` and implement that protocol in `ViewController`. When `ViewController` creates `secondVC`, it sets the delegate of `secondVC` to itself. That gives `secondVC` a pointer to its delegate (it shouldn't care whether its a `ViewController` or some other kind of object, as long as the delegate implements the right methods).

Answer (score 0):

first VC .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol textViewChildDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)getStrings:(NSString*)string;

@end
@interface textViewChild : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>{

    UITextView     *textView;

}
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<textViewChildDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "textViewChild.h"



    @implementation textViewChild
    @synthesize delegate;
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }



    -(void)myWorkingMethod{


        // get string from textView
        [delegate getStrings:textView.text];


    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 240, 320, 240)];

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Now go to secondVC .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "textViewChild.h"
@interface TextViewViewController : UIViewController<textViewChildDelegate>{

    UITextView * myfirstTextView;


}

@end
```

and to .m file:

```
#import "TextViewViewController.h"

@implementation TextViewViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void)getStrings:(NSString *)string{


    myfirstTextView.text = string; // finally we get string from child view controller

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    myfirstTextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];


    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
```